# Ansible echo into file

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm struggling with some Ansible/YAML syntax here. How do I echo multiple lines (in append mode) in to a file? I also can't use the copy module (with the content arg) because it has to be appended.

This code:

```
- name: Write backup script for each app
  shell: echo | '
      line one
      line two
      line three
      ' >> /manager/backup.sh
```

errors out with nonsensical:

```
"stderr": "/bin/sh:  line one line two line three : command not found"
```

I'm using the pipe because I think it's how you tell Ansible you want multiple lines (with preserved formatting), but maybe it's being used as a shell pipe.

Comment: I'd suggest `lineinfile` module to prevent adding this lines on subsequent playbook runs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
- name: Write backup script for each app
  shell: |
    echo 'line one
    line two
    line three' >> /manager/backup.sh
```

or explicitly specifying newline with `printf`:

```
- name: Write backup script for each app
  shell: printf 'line one\n
    line two\n
    line three\n' >> /manager/backup.sh
```

---

The error message you get makes perfect sense: you tried to pipe (`|`) the output of the `echo` command to the `line one line two line three` command. As shell does not find the latter, it reports the command not existing. It's the same if you executed the following directly in shell:

```
echo | "line one line two line three" >> /manager/backup.sh
```

YAML uses `|` to indicate multi-line value, but when used directly after the key, not anywhere in the value field.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

```
ansible node -i hosts -m shell -a "echo 'line one\nline two\nline three' | sudo tee -a /tmp/test.file;"
```